# How to remove sequence reads contains more than 2 X from multifasta file?

Tags: sequence-alignment, ngs, parsing

I have 5000 protein sequences in one multifasta file. I found more reads have gaps as X in their reads. So, want to eliminate those reads completely (Whole protein seq) from the file. I am keeping filter criteria as if a read contains morethan 2 X ( continuesly or anywhere in the read) should be removed. Thanks in advance for your help.

The input sequence looks like this

```
>Prot1 
ANSTVKKKKLLLYYYSSSEERXFGHYFGHYFGHFYVHFGFYVHCEDYHF
>Prot2
ANSTVKKKKLLLYYYSSSEERXXXXXXXXXXXFGHYFGHYFGHFYVHFGFYVHCEDYHF
>Prot3
ANSTVKKKKLLLYYYSSSEERFGHYFGHYFGHFYVHFGFYVHCEDYHF
```

I want output Like this

```
>Prot3
ANSTVKKKKLLLYYYSSSEERFGHYFGHYFGHFYVHFGFYVHCEDYHF
```

Comment: Easy use Biopython "SequenceClean".You could do it as a Perl one liner or awk. Which of these solutions are you more familiar with?

Comment: Just for a record, X is not a gap but unknown amino acid.

Comment: Also, `>Prot1 ` seems to have only one X, hence I suppose it should be kept as well, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

A Biopytnon solution that works for `.gz` files too :-). The script make a script `filter_faa.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from Bio import SeqIO
from mimetypes import guess_type
import gzip

filename = sys.argv[1]

encoding = guess_type(filename)[1]
_open = partial(gzip.open, mode='rt') if encoding == 'gzip' else open

with _open(filename) as ffile:
    for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(ffile, 'fasta'):
        if seq_record.seq.count('X') < 3:
            print(seq_record.format("fasta"))
```

Then usage is

```
python3 filter_faa.py my.faa > my_filtered.faa
```

The `my_filtered.faa` then will contain

```
>Prot1
ANSTVKKKKLLLYYYSSSEERXFGHYFGHYFGHFYVHFGFYVHCEDYHF

>Prot3
ANSTVKKKKLLLYYYSSSEERFGHYFGHYFGHFYVHFGFYVHCEDYHF
```

The filtering condition is hard-coded. You could potentially parametrise it if you feel like later you might want to filter by a different number of unknown aa.

Comment: it's generally better to explicitly close the open file handle, which won't happen for your gzip.open() case, could be modified, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52839332

Comment: Ha, I always wondered if there is an elegant soltion for opening it with/out gz. Cheers Chris!

Comment: It is an elegant solution even without closing the filehandle

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**: as pointed out, this will not work for a multifasta as asked for in your original question. However it would work fine for a single line fasta

---

You could accomplish this with a single line of bash code if you would like (this assumes your fasta is in gzip format, if not just use cat):

```sh
zcat prot.fasta.gz | grep -E -v -B1 '(^>.*|^(.*X.*){3}$)' | grep -E -v '^--$'  - | gzip > prot.filtered.fasta.gzip
```

The `-v` option of grep inverts the regex, and the `-B1` will print out the line occuring before the current context. The `-B1` introduces `--` between the matches, which is why the second grep is there. Then you can immediately pipe it back into a zipped file

Comment: I guess this would not work if the aa sequence had more than one line, or am I missing something?

Comment: You would be correct, In which case this would not work with OP's original question.  Grep would still be a useful tool for the filtering. You could probably filter out any sequences which havae More then 3 x's then filter out any Protein s that no longer have sequences